# How to sort numbers correctly with Array.sort()?

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, numbers, numeric

In multiple browsers, the following code doesn't sort the numbers correctly:

```
a = new Array();
a.push(10);
a.push(60);
a.push(20);
a.push(30);
a.push(100);
document.write(a.sort())
```

It returns `10,100,20,30,60`.

Anyone know why?

Comment: Just a late comment, if you do not implicitly pass a function then you are telling it to sort an array of unicodes/strings.
in unicode 100 is less than 20.

Comment: The "reason why" is `Array.sort` sorts [**alphabetically**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alphabetical_order), not numerically.  For numeric sort: `a.sort(function(a,b){return a-b})`.

Answer (score 81, accepted):

> I've tried different numbers, and it always acts as if the 0s aren't there and sorts the numbers correctly otherwise. Anyone know why?

You're getting a lexicographical sort (e.g. convert objects to strings, and sort them in dictionary order), which is the default sort behavior in Javascript:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort

> ```
> array.sort([compareFunction])
> ```
>
> Parameters
>
> compareFunction
>
> Specifies a function that defines the sort order. If omitted, the array is sorted lexicographically (in dictionary order) according to the string conversion of each element.

In the ECMAscript specification (the normative reference for the generic Javascript), [ECMA-262, 3rd ed.](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/standards/Ecma-262-arch.htm), section 15.4.4.11, the default sort order is lexicographical, although they don't come out and say it, instead giving the steps for a conceptual sort function that calls the given compare function if necessary, otherwise comparing the arguments when converted to strings:

```
13. If the argument comparefn is undefined, go to step 16.
14. Call comparefn with arguments x and y.
15. Return Result(14).
16. Call ToString(x).
17. Call ToString(y).
18. If Result(16) < Result(17), return −1.
19. If Result(16) > Result(17), return 1.
20. Return +0.
```

Comment: @maxhud, if you want to post something, add your own answer.

Comment: this was asked to me in interview..lol i knew js is weird! but i love it lol

Answer (score 180):

```
a.sort(function(a,b){return a - b})
```

These can be confusing.... check [this link](http://www.javascriptkit.com/javatutors/arraysort.shtml) out.

Comment: In ES6 it's even more elegant: `a.sort((a, b) => a - b)`

Comment: quiet elegant. I used the ES6Version of the same and works like a charm, and why this is not the answer????

Comment: @Rohith This answer was written when I had only just recently joined SO, and it's honestly not a very well written answer either. :P The solution is wonderful, but it doesn't explain why the issue occurs, so I think Jason's answer should definitely be the marked solution.  I'm glad you found my answer useful, though!

Comment: small note here -- generally speaking you never want to reuse variable names (even if they're block scoped). we're sorting an array called 'a' and then reusing 'a' to represent an array item. if this is confusing anyone 'a' is not the same value. 

to clarify: 

`array.sort((a, b) => a - b)`

Comment: That's wrong when the question is "how to sort numbers correctly".
It doesn't take NaNs into account, e.g. `[0, -1, 3.14, 0/0, -100, 10, 0.2]`

Answer (score 35):

The default sort for arrays in Javascript is an [alphabetical search](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort). If you want a numerical sort, try something like this:

```
var a = [ 1, 100, 50, 2, 5];
a.sort(function(a,b) { return a - b; });
```

Answer (score 19):

You can use a sort function :

```
var myarray=[25, 8, 7, 41]
myarray.sort( function(a,b) { return a - b; } );
// 7 8 25 41
```

Look at http://www.javascriptkit.com/javatutors/arraysort.shtml

Comment: It's `a - b`; this returns it in reverse order.

Comment: As suggested by @pimvdb please correct the answer to be a-b.

Answer (score -6):

try this:

```
a = new Array();
a.push(10);
a.push(60);
a.push(20);
a.push(30);
a.push(100);
a.sort(Test)

document.write(a);


function Test(a,b)
{
    return a > b ? true : false;
}
```

Comment: check code here: http://jsfiddle.net/8yxtg/1/

Comment: First, `a > b ? false : true` can be simplified to `a < b`. Second, you actually need to return `-1`, `0` or `1` so this is not completely correct (although it might work fine).

Comment: The sort function should return -1, 0 or 1 (not true/false). Most implementations will actually accept <any-negative-number>, 0 or <any-positive-number> which is why `return a-b` usually works for numbers.

Comment: `code`return a - b`code` does not manage correctly negative numbers... a < b does.

Comment: @Max uhh... it manages negative numbers just fine, try it.

Comment: @pimvdb - a > b works fine on ios platform - but for android platform, a > b ? 1 : -1    was needed. Samir got downvoted - but his answer and your response helped me