# Find the oldest date in a list of dates

Tags: javascript, date

I need a help in coming up with function in JavaScript. The function should be able to find the oldest date from the list of dates in this format `yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss`. So the function would receive a text and among the lines it should find the oldest date entry and select text associated with that date.

Also if there is Java solution for this problem that could work to and I will use something to include Java inside JavaScript.

Comment: What have you tried? Are you getting errors? Posting some code would be helpful.

Comment: You cannot (easily) include Java in JavaScript. What "something" would you have used?

Comment: you can't do it in javascript, you need jquery

Comment: @webarto If you can't do it in JavaScript, then by definition you can't do it in jQuery either since jQuery is just a big ball of wibbly-wobbly, JavaScripty-wipty... stuff.

Comment: @Kolink gonna save that for future reference

Comment: @Kolink that is quite possible the best description of jQuery I have ever read.

Comment: In the olden days, there used to be some functionality of applets that let JS scripts and Java applets pass stuff back and forth.  Not sure if it still exists, as i haven't played with applets for like 10 years.

Comment: @cHao It still exists and is still very useful when needed. I last used it about a year and a half ago.

Comment: @webarto: You know that [this](http://i.stack.imgur.com/TdrW7.gif) is only a [meme](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/19492/183280)?

Comment: @Bergi: He's well aware.  It's a running joke in the PHP chat.  :)

Comment: Just so you know guys I was working on this one for a client and he didn't reply to me so I put this on hold.

You CAN include java into javascript when you make scripts for iMacros. I found a code on their forum and I can post it here if anyone needs it. 
This question will be a good reference for my future works.

Answer (score 3):

Here is how you would do it...

1. Iterate over the dates as an array, turning them into Unix epochs.
2. Find the oldest with `Math.min.apply(Math, arrayOfDates)` or better yet `Math.min(...arrayOfDates)`.

Answer (score 3):

This'd work, assuming `datelist` is the string and that each date is on its own line:

```
var oldest = (function() {var o = ":", c, a=datelist.split(/\r?\n/); while(c=a.shift()) o = o < c ? o : c; return o;})();
```

Breaking that down, here's how it works: It's basically creating a function, running it, then getting its return value. The function is like so:

```
var o = ":",
  // ":" comes after "9" in the character map, so it will be greater than any date
    c, a = datelist.split(/\r?\n/);
  // split on newlines, accomodating both \r and `\r\n` options.
while(c = a.shift()) {
  // basically loop through each date
    o = o < c ? o : c;
  // if the current oldest date is older than the one we're looking at, keep the old one
  // otherwise the new date is older so should be kept
}
return o;
  // return the result
```

Comment: @webarto Why the hell should I when I just did it perfectly well in raw JS?

Answer (score 0):

You can convert all the date strings to [`Date`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) objects, and then sort your list [numerically](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7000851/1048572) and get the first item. Alternatively you can just apply [`Math.min`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/min) on it to get the lowest value, if you don't need a sorted list.

```
var minDate = Math.min.apply(null, datestrings.map(Date));
```

Or, as your format does have leading zeroes, a simple [string sort](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) will do the same. To only search for a minimum string, you can use this:

```
var min = datestrings.reduce(function(min, cur) {
    return cur < min ? cur : min;
});
```

Comment: A sort is overkill unless the OP also wants the second oldest etc.. Sorting is a minimum of `O(n log n)` whereas scanning is `O(n)`.

Comment: That's true, I already extended the answer with search code. `datestrings.sort()[0]` would just be the shortest to write :-)

Comment: I think `Array.prototype.reduce` is fairly new to JS, and `sort` returns whether it succeeded or not so dereferencing it wouldn't work ;)

Answer (score 0):

A Wibbly-wobbly dollarsy-wollarsy example using jquery:

```
  $("body").append($("<div>").attr("id", "q")); //some gratuitous jquery
  var timelist = "2012-03-03 10:14:21 \r\n 2012-05-15 21:21:12\r\n 2012-07-01 10:19:19\r\n2012-02-11 21:21:12";
  var datelist = timelist.split("\r\n");
  var oldest = ":";
  $.each(datelist, function (a) {
    var trimmedThis = $.trim(this);
    if (trimmedThis < latest) oldest = trimmedThis;
  });
  $("#q").text(oldest); //just to beef up the $ count
```