# Find minimum and maximum dates

Tags: javascript, date, datetime, max, minimum

There is an array:

```
var a = new Array();
```

It contains date entries like this: '2012-09-12 09:20', etc

I need to find minimum and maximum dates using javascript. This code does not work with time values.

```
var minT = Math.min.apply(Math, a);
var maxT = Math.max.apply(Math, a);
```

How can I solve this problem in javascript? It seems to be quite complex as I'm not very experienced in this language.

Comment: Does your array contain date strings, or `Date` objects?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Find the oldest date in a list of dates](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12083270/find-the-oldest-date-in-a-list-of-dates)

Comment: @Rocket: Strings, it would have worked with `Date` objects ;-)

Comment: Convert your date strings to date objects `new Date(string)` and you can get the date as milliseconds since 1970-01-01 00:00:00+0000.

Comment: @Rocket: It contains date strings, which complicates the problem

Comment: @some: If I convert to Date, then alert(minT) says 'Infinity'

Comment: @YouKuper are you sure that all strings are in proper format?

Comment: @YouKuper Then you have done something wrong. A date can never be Infinity. It can be 'Invalid date' and when converted to a number that is NaN.

Comment: Just to add something - convert your date to unix timestamp and you can use `Math.min.apply` and `Math.max.apply` because unix timestamp is a single integer.

Comment: @DavidBélanger: Converting them to `Date` objects works too.

Comment: @Rocket Yes, it does. But, it's slower.

Comment: @Rocket Converting them to objects is a way to convert them to timestamps. You can easily get number of milliseconds since 1970-01-01 00:00:00 UTC (without leap seconds).

Comment: possible duplicate of [Min/Max of dates in an array?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7143399/min-max-of-dates-in-an-array)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If your array contains `Date` objects, then this should work.  If it just contains strings like `'2012-09-12 09:20'`, then you can sort them, and get the 1st and last elements.

```
a.sort(function(a, b){
    return Date.parse(a) - Date.parse(b);
});

var maxT = a[a.length-1];
var minT = a[0];
```

Comment: Nice, except that the order of items in the array is reorganized and that it creates a lot of objects (could be a problem if there are many dates)

Comment: @some: Might not be the best solution, but it was the 1st think I could think of :-)

Comment: sorting the array is not really efficient - `O(n log n)` while min&max need `O(2n)`. Also, your sort method creates two `Date` objects in each comparison - while an alphanumerical sort would have the same result.

Comment: @Bergi: An alphanumeric sort would only work if the dates were in the same format.  This will work for all formats.  Also, I know it's not very efficient, it's just all I could think of :-P

Comment: @Bergi Alphanumeric sort only works if the pars are in the right order Y-M-D H:M:S, not for D/M/Y or M/D/Y.

Comment: Not sure, but `Date.parse` may be better than `new Date`.

Comment: @Bergi I'm aware of that the one date that OP posted was in that format. I'm not surprised if all of OP dates is in that format. However, it is not a generic solution. My comment was just a reminder that it only works in with the right format.

Comment: Is `getTime` easier/clearer in the comparator, i.e. `a.sort(function(a, b) { return a.getTime() - b.getTime(); })`

Comment: @patricksurry: If you have an array of `Date` objects, you can just do `return a-b;`.  `Date`s are converted automatically using `.getTime()` (for proof enter `+new Date()` in your console).

Comment: Hmm.  Why does `[new Date('2015-01-01'), new Date('2015-03-01'), new Date('2015-02-01')].sort()` sort from largest to smallest (in Chrome at least), whereas `[new Date('2015-01-01'), new Date('2015-03-01'), new Date('2015-02-01')].sort(function(a,b) { return a-b; })` sorts correctly in ascending order?

Comment: @patricksurry: According to the docs for `.sort`: If *compareFunction* is not supplied, elements are sorted by converting them to strings and comparing strings in Unicode code point order.  This is why it doesn't sort as you expect.

Comment: Ah, thanks, that makes sense.  Too many implicit conversions.  Sorry for taking this off topic.

Answer (score 3):

[`Math.min`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/min)/[`max`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/max) only compares numbers, not strings. Don't use them to represent the dates, but use [`Date` objects](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) - they will be compared by their internal timestamp number. Still, the max/min will return that internal number, so you would need to convert it back to a `Date` (see [Min/Max of dates in an array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7143399)):

However, if you want to use the strings or can't use the recreated Date, you will need to run manually through the array - either with a for-loop, or the ES5.1-only iterator method [`.reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce):

```
var min = datestrings.reduce(function(min, cur) {
    return cur < min ? cur : min;
});

// is equivalent to
var min = datestrings[0];
for (var i=1; i<datestrings.length; i++)
    if (datestrings[i] < min)
        min = datestrings[i];
```

If your code does not need to be efficient, you also just can sort the array and get the first and last values. The default alphanumeric sorting will do it for your date format, so this is really simple:

```
datestrings.sort();
var min = datestrings[0],
    max = datestrings[datestrings.lengh-1];
```

Answer (score 1):

This should do it:

```
var maxT=new Date(Math.max.apply(null,a));
var minT=new Date(Math.min.apply(null,a));
```

If you must work with strings you could define a function:

```
function maxDate(data){
    var max = '';
    for(var i=0; i<data.length; i++)
        if(data[i]>max)
            max=data[i];
    return max;
}
```

And then:

```
var maxT=maxDate(a);
```

**DISCLAIMER:** This second method will only work if all the date strings are in the same format, if you have different format dates in your array you will not be able to use this function.

Comment: This only works if the array contains `Date` objects.  It contains strings here.

Comment: @Rocket you're right, edited my answer to properly answer the question

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
var maxDate=new Date(Math.max.apply(null,dates));
var minDate=new Date(Math.min.apply(null,dates));
```

I found it on an earlier [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7143399/min-max-of-dates-in-an-array)

Answer (score 0):

Is the array filled with Date objects?
If so, compare them using them, and sort them using one of the many known algorithms.

If not, recreate the array with Date objects, one for each of them, and do as I said above, by ordering the array.