# Array sort method unexpected behavior

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, sorting

I have an array having values are **1,10,6,8,7** and I want to sort this using `sort()` method, It's giving result like this **1,10,6,7,8** rather than **1,6,7,8,10**

*I wrote code below :*

```
var arr = [1,10,6,8,7];
arr.sort();
document.write(arr);
```

[image: Snap code]

Can anyone have idea about this?

Comment: It reads 10 not as ten, but as one zero. Maybe this is helpful? stackoverflow.com/questions/1063007/how-to-sort-an-array-of-integers-correctly

Comment: Refer this link https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var scores = [1, 10, 21, 2]; 
scores.sort(); // [1, 10, 2, 21]
// Watch out that 10 comes before 2,
// because '10' comes before '2' in Unicode code point order.
```

Refer this link https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort

Answer (score 2):

10 is before 2 in unicode. You need to help the `sort()` function to determine which element is before which.

```
arr.sort(function(a, b) {
  return a - b;
});
```

Comment: Code formatting and a sentence to explain the line of code would be great.

Answer (score 0):

From the documentation:

> If compareFunction is not supplied, elements are sorted by converting them to strings and comparing strings in Unicode code point order.

This is why `sort` on an array of number is "weird": because it compares the string representation of the numbers.

In a unicode point of view: `"10" < "2"`.

Answer (score 0):

You're getting a lexicographical sort (e.g. convert objects to strings, and sort them in dictionary order), which is the default sort behavior in Javascript:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort

Original answer:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/7000924/7462678

Answer (score 0):

According to the Mozilla Developer Network, "The default sort order is according to string Unicode code points.". 10 comes before 2 in Unicode code point order. You would need to pass in a comparison function to the sort function, which would compare the numbers.

[Array.prototype.sort - Mozilla Developer Network](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort)