# How does sort() works in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

I am using sort() for quite sometime in JavaScript but today I encountered something which is confusing.

***Example 1***
Here is a snapshot of my chrome console where I am trying to sort an array.

[image]
**Step 1.** **aa** is an array decalred with some integer values.
**Step 2.** Result of **aa.sort()** is unexpected, as yellow highlights clearly shows that that array is not sorted.
**Step 3.** Sorting the array using a 

compare function ** inside the sort. And this works perfectly.

---

*Example 2*
Here is another example -
[image].

Simply using **sort()

 sorts the array in default ascending order while same is not happening in *Example 1*.

I want to know exactly what goes inside **sort()** method.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Array.sort() doesn't sort numbers correctly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7000851/array-sort-doesnt-sort-numbers-correctly)

Comment: You say it's integers, are you sure it's not rather strings?

Comment: No, these are integers only.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

See [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort):

> The default sort order is according to string Unicode code points.

And when you sort by string, `100` is smaller than `20` because it tests character-by-character.

Answer (score 2):

From this [post](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_sort.asp):

> By default, the sort() method sorts the values as strings in
>   alphabetical and ascending order.
>
> This works well for strings ("Apple" comes before "Banana"). However,
>   if numbers are sorted as strings, "25" is bigger than "100", because
>   "2" is bigger than "1".
>
> Because of this, the sort() method will produce an incorrect result
>   when sorting numbers.
>
> You can fix this by providing a "compare function".

Answer (score 1):

Array.prototype.sort() is a higher order function. You can use a compare function as an argument to get right results:

```
let myArray = [6,7,3,5,4,1,45];
myArray.sort((n1, n2) => n1 - n2);
// result => [1, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 45]
```

Comment: The question always says they can pass a sort function to get the correct results. They are asking why they don't get the results they expect with the default sort function.

Answer (score -2):

**Numbers are converted to strings.** 
So it thinks like this:

```
[a, aa, aaa, b, bb, bbb] // makes sense

[1, 11, 111, 2, 22, 222] // um, only makes sense as strings!
```