# how to return the lowest index of the array?

Tags: javascript

For example, `getIndexToIns([1,2,3,4], 1.5)` should return `1` because it is greater than `1` (index `0`), but less than `2` (index `1`).

Likewise, `getIndexToIns([20,3,5], 19)` should return `2` because once the array has been sorted it will look like `[3,5,20]` and `19` is less than `20` (index `2`) and greater than `5` (index `1`).

**this is my code**

```
function getIndexToIns(arr, num) {
  // Find my place in this sorted array.
  arr = arr.sort();
  num = Math.floor(num);
  for(let i=0;i<arr.length;i++){
  }
  return num;
}

getIndexToIns([690, 60], 59);
```

Comment: What have you tried? What if the number is less than all in the array? Simplest IMO would be to `if (arr[i] > num) return i - 1;` in your loop, which returns -1 if `num` is less than all the entries.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [`.findIndex()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex) to find the first element in your sorted array which is larger than your passed `num` element:

```js
const getIndexToIns = (arr, num) => {
  const res = arr.sort((a, b) => a-b).findIndex(n => n > num);
  return res === -1 ? arr.length : res;
}

console.log(getIndexToIns([1,2,3,4], 1.5));
console.log(getIndexToIns([20,3,5], 19));
console.log(getIndexToIns([20,3,5], 100)); // 3 (array length)
```

Comment: Checking for `-1`  from `findIndex()` and returning the array length might be a nice touch.

Comment: @MarkMeyer nice idea, I've added that in

Comment: @RushikeshGanesh If the answer resolved your issue, please [mark it as accepted](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/289255) by clicking on the grey checkmark on the left

Answer (score 1):

Here the solution

```js
function getIndexToIns(arr, num) {
  var counter = 0;
  // Find my place in this sorted array.
  arr = arr.sort();
  num = Math.floor(num);

  for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    if (num > arr[i]) {
      counter++
    } else {
      break;
    }
  }
  return counter;
}

var count = getIndexToIns([690, 60, 55, 2], 59);
console.log(count);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is like one small part of insertion sort (which you can read about [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/insertion-sort/)).
What you are trying to do is to just compare the `num` with each element of sorted array `arr`, until you find a number which is greater than `num`.

So it'd look something like this:

```
for(let i=0;i<arr.length;i++){
    if(num <= arr[i])
        return i;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

here is a code you may try

```js
function getIndexToIns(a, b) {
  let ind = 0;
  for (var i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
    if (b < a[i]) {
      ind++;
    }
  }
  return ind
}

console.log(getIndexToIns([20, 3, 5], 19));
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
function getIndexToIns(arr, num) {
    var return_val;
  // Find my place in this sorted array.
  arr = arr.sort();
  num = Math.floor(num);
  for(let i=0;i<arr.length;i++){
    if(arr[i]>num){
        return_val = arr[i-1];
    }
  }
 return return_val;
}

var return_value = getIndexToIns([690, 60], 59);
console.log(return_value);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Because `arr.sort()` sorting does not sort the array accurately, check this: [Array.sort() doesn't sort numbers correctly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7000851/array-sort-doesnt-sort-numbers-correctly)

This code is working fine

```js
function getIndexToIns(arr, num) {
  // Find my place in this sorted array.
  arr.sort(function(a, b) { return a - b; });
  num = Math.floor(num);
  //console.log(arr)
  var found = arr.findIndex(function(e) {
    return e > num;
  });
  return found;
}

console.log(
  getIndexToIns([1, 2, 3, 4], 1.5),
  getIndexToIns([20, 3, 5], 19),
  getIndexToIns([20, 3, 5], 19)
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```js
function getIndexToIns(arr, num) {
  // Find my place in this sorted array.
  var index = 0
  arr.sort((a, b) => a - b)
  for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    if (num > arr[i]) {

    } else {
      index = i
      break
    }
  }
  return index;
}

console.log(
  getIndexToIns([1, 2, 3, 4], 1.5)
)
```